# Does restart of the computer kill docker containers?

Tags: docker

I have a few containers running in my local machine but since my computer is responding extremely slow as I haven't shut it down in many months. But I don't want my containers to be deleted if I restart my computer in order to make my computer fast again. I want to know will it kill my local running docker containers if I restart it? or does it keep docker containers in memory?

Comment: It can't keep them in memory when the computer restarts. Everything is basically turned off momentarily and then restarted, which means any running applications (including Docker) are restarted as well.

Comment: What part of the state are you worried about being "deleted"? In general, anything you want to persist across invocations should be kept in a volume.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All your container will be stopped when you reboot your computer. Docker will try to gracefully stop them.

If you run your container with the `--rm` flag, the container will be deleted on stop, otherwise, it will continue to exists.

If you run your container with the `--restart` flag with the value `always`, when the docker daemon start, the container will be started. Else, you need to start them manually with `docker start <container id or name>`